# How do we properly clean a tumble dryer?

Tags: cleaning, dryer

There were [a couple of chocolates](http://browardsaves.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/hersheys-kisses-deal.jpg) not removed from the pockets of my trousers when I threw it into the washing machine for a spin.

After the wash, I threw the trousers (among other clothes) into the tumble dryer for an hour and a half.

When I took out my clothes, the entire tumble dryer reeks of chocolate. I've cleared the filter of the tumble dryer (there were literally small broken pieces of chocolates and wrappers stuck there) but it seems as though most of the chocolate had melted onto the walls of the tumble drum. I suspect that some small broken chocolate pieces had even made their way into the gaps separating the tumble drum and the tumble box itself.

In short, the whole thing is in a mess.

What's the best way to properly clean a tumble dryer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wipe down the inside of the dryer with soapy water to remove any chocolate that could come in contact with your clothes as this should prevent any of your clothes from picking up stains.

As for the chocolate that might have made its way past the drum, there's no easy way to remove this without disassembling the dryer, but I wouldn't really worry about it too much.  If you were to take apart your dryer, you'd likely find all sorts of debris in there.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I was wondering wouldn't the inside of the dryer be soapy? How do we remove the *soap* afterwards?

Comment: Wipe down with a damp soap free cloth.  Go easy on the soap - you don't need to fill the dryer with suds, just need something to help cut the fat/grease.

Comment: If you dry a load of towels after you wipe down the inside of the dryer, that should help clean up any residual soap/chocolate, you can always wash the towels again if they get soapy or chocolatey. I'd probably run the dryer before the initial wipe down to heat it up and melt the chocolate and use warm water to wipe it down.

Comment: Make that a load of rags, not towels. @Johnny

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can clean it with mild soap and water.  I would use paper towel as a mild abrasive and see how well it cleans.  If the chocolate was high quality (dark chocolate with cocoa content >= 50%), it will have less fat in it so less soap is needed.

As for the crevices, the only way to be sure is to disassemble the dryer to expose the mating surfaces.  Most modern dryers are easy to disassemble—provided you know the "trick".  The disassembly technique varies by brand, but all the recent dryers I know of can have the drum removed without moving the dryer and without touching the top.

1. Turn off the circuit breaker.
2. Unplug the dryer.
3. Examine the front of the dryer, including inside the door, for exposed screws.  Almost certainly these are machine screws with a hex and Phillips combination head.
4. Remove all the visible screws, even if they don't seem to hold anything together.  Cost savings production engineering means that the high paid assembly workers don't waste any time installing ornamental screws.
5. See what comes off and set it aside.
6. Repeat at 4. until the drum is exposed.
7. You probably don't want to remove the drum as that threatens the drive belt which is bothersome to reassemble.

Comment: The problem with blindly removing all visible screws without knowing what they connect to is that you might loosen some interior and hard to reach bracket that you didn't need to loosen and which will be hard to reattach without disassembling more than you planned to. I'd start with only removing the screws that look like they need removal, and then if you can't get the parts off that you want to take off, figure out which additional screws you need to remove.

Comment: If you're going to start taking it apart, you may as well locate the service manual with diagrams so you only remove whats necessary